# Не работает код MySQL PHP

Tags: mysql

Не работает код. При выводе `$article` ничего не выводит. Если убрать `$max_date` в `WHERE date='$max_date'` и подставить значение получаемое в `$max_date` на его меcто, то все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$max_date = mysql_query("SELECT max(date) date FROM example ORDER BY date DESC");

$article = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE date='$max_date'");
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` - возвращает результат запроса - это массив) И вообще, так юзать - это говнокод, те нада зделать выборку одним  запросом